# Extract trace id from external service

Tags: spring-cloud, trace, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth

I was recently upgrading to Spring Cloud Sleuth 2.0.0 and facing now the issue to correctly extract the trace id from an external service.

There is **ExternalService** (not under my control) which is publishing messages into a ActiveMQ queue with a header value "X-B3-TraceId", a 16 chars long String like "1234567890abcdef".

I will take out this message from the queue in **MyService** with a JmsListener annotated message:

```
...
/**
 * Pulls the messages from the ActiveMQ server which are located in the destination queue.
 */
@JmsListener(destination = "${destination}")
void pullMessage(Message<String> msg) throws IOException {
    String payload = msg.getPayload();

    Span span = interceptor.nextSpan(message);

...
```

When I'm using the TracingChannelInterceptor to get the traceId from the headers, it will not put the correct id into the log output.

```
2018-07-01 21:59:10.529  INFO [MyService,fae6f4dac5903bb0,fae6f4dac5903bb0,false] 19276 --- [           main] ...
```

I actually expected this line.

```
 2018-07-01 21:59:10.529  INFO [MyService,1234567890abcdef,fae6f4dac5903bb0,false] 19276 --- [           main] ...
```

Why is Sleuth modifiying the value and how can I propagate my trace context correctly to be able to trace down the messages across both systems?

In the previous versions of Sleuth I extracted the traceId from the header by using this method.

```
private static Optional<Span> extractFromHeaders(Message<String> msg) {
    Optional<Map.Entry<String, Object>> traceIdValue = msg.getHeaders().entrySet().stream()
            .filter(header -> header.getKey().equals(TraceMessageHeaders.TRACE_ID_NAME) ||
                    header.getKey().equals("X-B3-TraceId") || header.getKey().equals("jms_correlationId"))
            .findFirst();

    String traceId = traceIdValue.map(headerEntry -> headerEntry.getValue().toString());
    long id = new BigInteger(traceId, 16).longValue();

    return Span.builder().traceId(id).build();
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: If you check the `MessageHeaderPropagation` class we're taking into consideration the new `spanTraceId` and the legacy headers `X-B3-TraceId`. Why is the latter legacy? Cause it contains hyphens that most systems don't accept. 

Anyways we do propagate both the legacy and non-legacy headers. It will be difficult to help you without a sample.